# react-native google mobile ads

Tags: react-native, admob, ads, google-ads-api

I have implemented [react-native-google-mobile-ads.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-mobile-ads).  all. thing are. working fine but i want but there is some issue.

1. When ever a system dialogue is open. like `Alert.alert()` then an app open ads is appeared.
2. The Second issue is that app open ads appears after the interstitial ad is closed.
3. App Open ads are appears when ever a permission dialogue is opened.
4. I want to hide screen content behind the app open ads.

[image]